# installation doesn't proceed : when starting the setup of  VMware 8

Tags: windows-7, installation, vmware-workstation

When i start the setup of VMware 8 , an incomplete window of installation opens up and installation doesn't start/end .

This type of window appears:

[image]

I have a 32 bit processor with win7 installed . What could be the reason for this? Please recommend something so that i can install VMware.

Answer (score 0):

From [VMware Workstation 8.0 Release Notes](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws80/doc/releasenotes_workstation_80.html):

> Installation Requirements
>
> When you install Workstation, the installer performs checks to make sure the host system has a processor that meets the following requirements. You cannot install Workstation if the host system does not meet these requirements.
>
> - 64-bit x86 CPU
> - LAHF/SAHF support in long mode
>
> You can use CPU-Z or a similar utility to determine if the host system CPU is 64-bit capable. CPU-Z shows EM64T (Intel) or AMD64 (AMD) if the processor is 64-bit capable.
>
> If you plan to install a 64-bit guest operating system in a virtual machine, the host system must have one of the following processors. Workstation will not allow you to install a 64-bit guest operating system if the host system does not have one of these processors.
>
> - AMD CPU that has segment-limit support in long mode.
> - Intel CPU that has VT-x support. VT-x support must be enabled in the host system BIOS. The BIOS settings that must be enabled for VT-x support vary depending on the system vendor. See [VMware KB article 1003944](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1003944) for information on how to determine if VT-x support is enabled.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please note that any material copied verbatim from other sources should be attributed properly, preferably in the form of a link to the source. Also you should make sure to format such material as a blockquote.